# What are options for android UI optimization?

Tags: android

I have an app which has a tons of graphic elements, I tried to eliminate layout complexity by using RelativeLayout and wondering what else can be done to speed up UI based on standard layout system with a lot of graphic elements?

Comment: Checking Lint Errors is definetly an option, but i guess somebody with 61.8k reputation already did that.

Comment: You can check blog by [Romain Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298575/romain-guy) http://www.curious-creature.org/category/android/, he writes often on performance topic. Especially take a look at this [article](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/01/android-performance-case-study/)